# How to fix a dictionary; "get is not a known member of None" in a Pylance language server prompt message

Tags: python, pylance

I love to use Pylance, but I am unable to fix this issue in dictionary get. The Pylance prompt message is as shown:

> "get is not a known member of None"

[image: Sample image]

#### Code

```
def validate_amount():
try:
    json_data = request.json
    def isfloat(num: str) -> bool:
        try:
            float(num)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
    amount_val = json_data.get('amount','0.0')
    amount_in_words = json_data.get('amount2words','')
    if isfloat(amount_val):
        split_amt = amount_val.split('.')
        response = split_amt
except Exception as e:
    response = f'An Error Occurred - {e}'
```

Below is the image for reference:

[image: Reference image]

Comment: It is a free pass because the error message ** *** *** *** ***was actually provided as text*** *** *** *** *** (could have been more clearly marked), but for onlookers: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating to "human language"

The error states exactly this:

> json_data might be None, and None does not have a method named 'get'

To fix this, you need to check if json_data is not None

```
def validate_amount():
try:
    json_data = request.json
    def isfloat(num: str) -> bool:
        try:
            float(num)
            return True
        except ValueError:
            return False
    # check if json_data is not None
    if json_data:
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^
        amount_val = json_data.get('amount','0.0')
        amount_in_words = json_data.get('amount2words','')
        if isfloat(amount_val):
            split_amt = amount_val.split('.')
            response = split_amt
    else:
        print('json_data is None')
except Exception as e:
    response = f'An Error Occurred - {e}'
```